# Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH CONNECT permission for AttributeSource

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCrkq.jpg)

Here is the error:

I'm making an application that scans bluetooth devices and I can't figure out what I'm missing. All permissions seem to be set.

Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH CONNECT permission for AttributeSource ( uid = 10151, packageName = com.test8, attributionTag = null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@197a119, next = null ): AdapterService getBondedDevices

Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

<!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices.
     If your app doesn't use Bluetooth scan results to derive physical
     location information, you can strongly assert that your app
     doesn't derive physical location. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

<!-- Needed only if your app makes the device discoverable to Bluetooth
     devices. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

<!-- Needed only if your app communicates with already-paired Bluetooth
     devices. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

<!-- Needed only if your app uses Bluetooth scan results to derive physical location. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: How are you requesting permission?

Comment: Did you fix it? I have the same problem

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

To fix it, I downgraded the emulator version from **Android 12** (API 31) to **Android 11** (API 30).